# Text pop-ups for clarification of user-facing form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

Thanks to a great deal of help from stackoverflow I've been able to create a beautiful form for data entry for clinical research, my last barrier is something I'm not sure is possible.

**Consider this situation:**

**`TextBoxA`**: Was the procedure a success?

**`ComboBoxA`**: "Successful";"Unsuccessful";"Don't know"

Since many different people will be putting data into this database, I'd like to have a button next to these boxes with a "**`?`**" in it, so that the user can click on it and a text box of sorts would pop up and define what exactly is meant by "Success" for instance, rather than pointing the users to a separate codebook or teaching them how to look in the variable description.

**How is this possible to implement?**

Comment: So within the combobox you want "?" next to each option, and to be able to click on them and have a pop up explain their definition?

Comment: Not within the combo box, just a separate button I can place next to the combo box for people who need clarification. I suppose my question is, specifically, can I make a button that pops up text?

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to your form in question in the Access Object List (on the very
   left), right click, Design View.
2. Click on `Label` at the top of Access under the Design Tab. Draw
   your label (a small box).
3. Click inside the label, and type a ?. Right click the label, select
   `Properties`.
4. Click on the `Event` tab. Click the `...` button correlating to the
   `On Click` event.
5. Select `Code Builder` -> `OK`.
6. Inside the `Private Sub LabelXX_Click()` event, paste this code:

   MsgBox "Success: Things went very well!" & vbCrLf & "Unsuccessful: This really sucked!"
7. Press `Ctrl+S` to save, and test it.

The `" & vbCrLf & "` adds a linebreak to your Message Box so you can have new lines.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Not knowing any VBA, I really appreciate the explicit instructions.